# Game Dev - Working with Screen Coordinates vs World Coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

A friend and myself are new to game development, and we had a discussion regarding World Coordinates and Screen Coordinates.

We are following a wonderful online tutorial series for libGDX and they are using a 100 PPM (pixels per meter) scaling factor.  If you re-size the screen, the scaling of objects no longer works.  My friend is convinced that it is not a problem, and he may be right.  But, I'm under the impression that when developing a game, the developers should typically only work with the pre-defined world coordinate system and let the camera transform it to the chosen screen coordinates. I do understand the need for reverse transformations when using mouseclicks, etc.  But, the placing and scaling of objects in the world space is my concern.

I would like to reach out to this community for some professional feedback.

Comment: I'm with you.  Pixels per anything is a problem because it will change not just your screen scale, but also the aspect ratio.  Figures on the screen will look skinny or wide depending on the screen itself.  That's bad.

Comment: `the developers should typically only work with the pre-defined world coordinate system and let the camera transform it to the chosen screen coordinates.` this is the right way

Comment: May be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ (I mean, "Game Dev"...)

Comment: @Marco13 actually libgdx is a game dev framework and therefore most questions could be at "game dev" to, but i guess it can also be asked and answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats one of the bigest problem of almost all Libgdx tutorials. They are great, but the pixel to meter/units conversation is just wrong.
Libgdx offers a great solution for that with `Camera` and an even better solution with the new `Viewport` classes (which under the hood work with `Camera`).

Its is really simple and will solve the problem of different screen sizes/aspect rations.
Just choose a `Virtual_Width` and `Virtual_Height` (think about it in meters or similar units).
For exampl, you have humans fighting each other in a 2D platformer game. LEts say our humans are 2m tall, so think about, how much screenspace should one human use? If we say, a human should take 1/10 of the screen space, our virtual height is 10*2=20. Now think about the primary aspect ration you are targeting. Lets say it is 16/9, so you have a virtual width of about 35.

Next, you need to think about what kind of `Viewport` you want. You sure want to use a `Viewport`, which supports `Virtual_Width` and `Virtual_Heigth`.
You may want a `Viewport`, which keeps the aspect ratio and fills the rest of the screen (if the screen has different aspect ratio) with black bars (`FitViewport`) or you may want the `Viewport` to fill the whole screen by stretching the units (`StretchViewport`).

Now just create the `Viewport` with your virtual width and heigth and update it in the `resize()` method with the given `width` and `height`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's be better name as Units per meter

And when you resize your screen you just set a new projective matrix, so everything works fine )

What you should worry about it's a aspect ratio.

Everything rest is doesn't matter.

So answering your question - Stay with world coordinates.
It also make simple add physics, light calculations, any dimensions ( 1.8 units instead 243 pixels )

Comment: Units per meter should be on the models themselves.  1.0 units in a model should be one meter, or whatever, and then set the view frustum to whatever the screen aspect ratio is.

Comment: If you calculate everything in units, there is no need for this conversation, units can also be meters, but thats just a name. In my opinion you should just calculate everything in your preffered unit and let the camera convert it to pixels.

Comment: That exactly what i mean